# equilibrium state of a galvanic cell

Tags: electrochemistry

At what conditions does equilibrium attain in the galvanic cell. What exactly happens at the equilibrium state of a galvanic cell redox reaction.
Consider the setup Zn|Zn2+||Cu2+|Cu,
   Where

- Anode: $\ce{Zn -> Zn^2+ + 2e}$
- Cathode: $\ce{Cu^2+ + 2e -> Cu}$
- Final reaction: $\ce{Zn + Cu^2+  -> Zn^2+ + Cu}$

Here the electrons would flow from Anode to cathode through a metallic wire which connects the two half cells.
There comes a stage where the $\ce{Zn^2+}$ ions get piled up in anode compartment and depletion of $\ce{Cu^2+}$ ions in the cathode compartment. At one stage the reaction stops which is when the cell/battery power is all utilised. 
But where does the equilibrium state come from?
Will the equilibrium reaction occur when the salt bridge is connected?
The reason I stressed more on equilibrium state is because of the equilibrium constant appearing in the Nernst equation. I'm pretty much in  a confused state reagarding the concept. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The nernst equation calculates at what voltage would the hypothetical cell be at equilibrium. At equilibrium, the current is zero. This voltage is then used to create a "ranking" of the (half) reactions so as to predict which will happen "first" or prioritized.

Comment: when the current becomes zero, how can the cell be at equilibrium, i mean no transfer of electrons takes place due to development of excess potential near respective electrodes.

Comment: Sure there is transfer of electrons. Just the same amount each direction. Equilibrium. The forward reaction rate equals the backward one.